# Android WebView to use OKHttp client?

Tags: android, webview, okhttp

I'm trying to use OKHTTP for a webview because I need to access the response headers. The problem is using this code the webview displays plain html instead of rendering it.

Any thoughts?

```
class WebViewClientImpl(val webView: WebView): WebViewClient() {

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    override fun shouldInterceptRequest(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): WebResourceResponse {
        return handleRequestViaOkHttp(url = request.url.toString())
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private fun handleRequestViaOkHttp(url: String): WebResourceResponse {
        try {
            val okHttpClient = UnsafeOkHttpClient.getUnsafeOkHttpClient()
            val call = okHttpClient.newCall(Request.Builder().url(url).build())
            val response = call.execute()

            return  WebResourceResponse(
                    response.header("content-type", "text/html"),
                    response.header("content-encoding", "utf-8"),
                    response.body().byteStream()
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            return  WebResourceResponse(null, null, null)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: try WebResourceResponse(
                  null,
                    null,
                    response.body().byteStream()
            )
and in exception block simply return null

Answer (score 3):

I have same problem and solve it by **NOT providing any mimetype and encoding**. I couldn't set null, because it was crashing with it.

```
    WebViewClient client = new WebViewClient() {
        private OkHttpClient okHttp = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();

        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
            Request okHttpRequest = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
            try {
                Response response = okHttp.newCall(okHttpRequest).execute();
                return new WebResourceResponse("","",response.body().byteStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    webView.setWebViewClient(client);
```